# Understanding 絵に描いたように

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, idioms

> **そんな絵に描いたように満ち足りた**ダーズリー家にも、たった一つ秘密があった。
>   In the Dursley family, *who were the very picture of contentment*, there was just one secret.

My translation of そんな絵に描いたように満ち足りた is purely a guess based on Jisho's definition of 絵に描いたように as "The very picture of...".

I can't understand how this phrase is used. Literally, I would translate そんな絵に描いたように満ち足りた as "Contented as though they had painted on such a picture". So I can kind of see how it works, but what is そんな needed for?

Could you give some other examples using this phrase so I can get a better feel for how it works?

Comment: 「そんな」 does not modify 「絵」 here; therefore it does not say "such a picture".

Comment: When your question includes a word like そんな, you might want to include some context.

Comment: @snailboat Indeed. Although the previous context is just a description of the Dursley family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そんな modifies ダーズリー家, so it means "Such a family, the Dursley family, who were the very picture of contentment, also had   just one secret."

Comment: 翻訳の意図は十分に理解できるのですが、"such" の直後に固有名詞ってどうなんでしょう・・

Comment: それは不自然なようですね。教えていただきありがとうございます。